# how to read a large file more than 2 GB using FileStream

Tags: .net, file, filestream

If i have a movie (MKV) and its size like 7 G.B how can i read it in FileStream .. 
we know that the maximum size of int is about 2,147 MB .. how to start read from index 3G.B .. since the .Read() method in FileStream takes the offset as an integer which 3 GB is out of int range .. ???

```
private void readingLargeFile(string path)
{
   int start = 3*(1024*1024*1024); 

   FileStream fs = new FileStream(path,FileMode.Open);
   fs.Read(data, start, (1024*8) );
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That read doesn't do what you think it does.

The offset in `Read` is the offset from the start of the *buffer* at which to start writing the data, it is not the offset in the *file* at which to start reading.

It's only usually non-zero if you've already partially populated the buffer and you want to tack on a bit more:

```
fs.Read (data,  0, 8 );   // Put first 8 bytes of file at buffer start
fs.Read (data, 16, 8 );   // Put next  8 bytes of file at buffer end
fs.Read (data,  8, 8 );   // Put first 8 bytes of file at buffer middle
```

With that example, the file containing `aaaaaaaabbbbbbbbcccccccc` would end up in the buffer as:

```
aaaaaaaaccccccccbbbbbbbb
```

You need to seek first, and that uses `long` as an offset value so it should be able to handle 8G files quite easily. Something like this would be a good starting point:

```
private void readingLargeFile (string path) {
   long start = 3L * 1024L * 1024L * 1024L; 

   FileStream fs = new FileStream (path, FileMode.Open);
   fs.Seek (start, SeekOrigin.Begin)
   fs.Read (data, 0, 8 * 1024 );
}
```

The `Seek` changes to current position of the file (where it will read from and/or write to, depending on the open mode and functions you call).

So `fs.Seek (start, SeekOrigin.Begin)` will set the file pointer to `start` characters from the beginning of the file. You can also specify other methods of movement than `SeekOrigin.Begin`, seeking from the current position like 27 bytes forward, or seeking from the end of the file.

Full detail are available on MSDN for both [`Seek`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.seek.aspx) and [`Read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.read.aspx).

Comment: thanks alot mr PAXDIABLO .. but can you explain to me what fs.Seek(start,SeekOrigin.Begin) does !!

Comment: No problems, @MurHafSoz - I added some explanation and links to the relevant MSDN documentation.